# IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) is not called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I wrote a custom attribute:

```
  public class VerifyOrderAttribute : RequiredAttribute   {
      protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
      {
         if (DoesOrderExist((string)value))
            return ValidationResult.Success;

         ValidationResult vr = new ValidationResult("Order does not exist");

         return vr;
        //return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
      }

      private bool DoesOrderExist(string sOrderSequence)
      {
         PullParts.PartProcessor o = new PullParts.PartProcessor();
         bool result = o.CheckOrder(sOrderSequence);
         return result;
      }
  }
```

I use VerifyOrder attribute with my property:

```
  [Required(ErrorMessage= "Order number is required")]
  [RegularExpression(@"\d{2}-\d{6}-\d{2}", ErrorMessage="Order number must be in format XX-XXXXXX-XX")]
  [VerifyOrder(ErrorMessage="Order number does not exist")]
  public global::System.String OrderNumber
  {
     get
     {
        return _OrderNumber;
     }
     set
     {
        _OrderNumber = value;
     }
  }
  private global::System.String _OrderNumber;
```

At my view, I called ValidationMessageFor():

```
<div>
    <label class="span2">*Order Number:</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Request.OrderNumber, new { @class = "span3" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Request.OrderNumber)
</div>
```

It looks like ValidationMessageFor does not call IsValid() for my custom attribute.  I want my custom attribute VerifyOrder to work just like Required attribute.  What do I need to do?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit** (Moved from comment)

I did check it in the controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MSDModel m) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        model.Request = m.Request; 
        model.SaveRequest(); 
        model.Request.OrderNumber = string.Empty; 
    } 
    return View(model);
}
```

but wait until the user submit is too late. I want to check to see if the order exists before I process it. And I need to show a visual indicator to user whether it exists or not. How can I achieve that behavior?

Comment: Are you checking `ModelState.IsValid` anywhere?

Comment: I did check it in the controller like this:
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Index(MSDModel m)
      {

         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
            model.Request = m.Request;
            model.SaveRequest();
            model.Request.OrderNumber = string.Empty;
         }
         return View(model);
      }
but wait until the user submit is too late.  I want to check to see if the order exists before I process it.  And I need to show a visual indicator to user whether it exists or not.  How can I achieve that behavior? Thanks

Comment: In your `[HttpPost]` `Index` method, if the order doesn't exist, does `Model.IsValid` return false? If so, it should be working as designed. It sounds like what you **want**, or what you're expecting, is client-side validation, but since you have to check for the existence of a record in a database, you can't do that. Additionally, you can't have automatic client-side validation with custom validation attributes anyway, because the framework doesn't know how to translate it to js. You could potentially make an ajax call to do the check, but I don't think that would really gain you anything.

Comment: thanks Jason. I ended up calling TryValidateModel() in my controller and let the user click on the button to submit before they see the message.